# GroupBy Arraylist key As map and marge values

Tags: java, java-8

I want to groupby map key as arraylist and marge values as value of map.

map is {[L1, L10]=[t1], [L1, L7]=[t2], [L1, L9]=[t3], [L1, L8]=[t4]}

want to convert should be: 
{[L1]=[t1,t2,t3,t4], [L10]=[t1], [L7]=[t2], [L9]=[t3],[L8]=[t4]}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

public class AdvisoryCache {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestObject t1=new TestObject("test1", "c1", "1");
        TestObject t2=new TestObject("test2", "c2", "2");
        TestObject t3=new TestObject("test3", "c1", "3");   
        TestObject t4=new TestObject("test4", "c3", "4");   
        TestObject t5=new TestObject("test5", "c1", "5");   
        TestObject t6=new TestObject("test6", "c4", "6");

        ArrayList<TestObject> testList=new ArrayList<>();
        testList.add(t1);
        testList.add(t2);
        testList.add(t3);
        testList.add(t4);
        testList.add(t5);
        testList.add(t6);


        ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object> s=testList
                .parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestObject::getClientId))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(k->getArrayValue(k.getKey()), v->getValue(v.getValue()), (k, v)->v,ConcurrentHashMap::new));

    System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static TestObject getValue(List<TestObject> v) {
        return v.get(0);

    }
    public static ArrayList getArrayValue(String k) {
        if(k.equalsIgnoreCase("c1")) {
             ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<>();
            a1.add("L1");
            a1.add("L7");
            return a1;
        }else if(k.equalsIgnoreCase("c2")) {
            ArrayList a1=new ArrayList<>();
            a1.add("L1");
            a1.add("L8");
            return a1;
        }else if(k.equalsIgnoreCase("c3")) {
            ArrayList a1=new ArrayList<>();
            a1.add("L1");
            a1.add("L9");
            return a1;
        }else {
            ArrayList a1=new ArrayList<>();
            a1.add("L1");
            a1.add("L10");
            return a1;
        }
    }
}


class TestObject {

    String name;
    String clientId;
    String differentValue;
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the clientId
     */
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    /**
     * @param clientId the clientId to set
     */
    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the differentValue
     */
    public String getDifferentValue() {
        return differentValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param differentValue the differentValue to set
     */
    public void setDifferentValue(String differentValue) {
        this.differentValue = differentValue;
    }

    public TestObject(String name, String clientId, String differentValue) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.differentValue = differentValue;

    }




}
```

map is {[L1, L10]=[t1], [L1, L7]=[t2], [L1, L9]=[t3], [L1, L8]=[t4]}

want to convert should be: 
{[L1]=[t1,t2,t3,t4], [L10]=[t1], [L7]=[t2], [L9]=[t3],[L8]=[t4]}

Comment: What is the type of the source and destination maps. How do we know what this L1, L2, t1 and t2 et.al is? Please check this out on how to provide a minimal and reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap with key as arraylist<String> and value also as arraylist<String>.  {[L1, L10]=[t1], [L1, L7]=[t2], [L1, L9]=[t3], [L1, L8]=[t4]}  want to convert key as String  and value asarraylist with marge.  {"L1"=[t1,t2,t3,t4], "L10"=[t1], [L7]=[t2],"L9"=[t3],[L8]=[t4]}

Answer (score 1):

Your `s` `Map` is actually a `ConcurrentHashMap<List<String>, TestObject>`, so don't use `ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object>`.

To get your desired `Map`, I processed the entries of the `s` `Map`, used `flatMap` to generate all pairs of (`"L#"`,`TestObject`) and used `collect(Collectors.groupingBy)` to group them by `"L#"`:

Here's the stream pipeline:

```
Map<String,List<TestObject>> out = 
   s.entrySet ()
    .stream ()
    .flatMap (e -> e.getKey ()
                    .stream ()
                    .map (k -> new SimpleEntry<>(k,e.getValue())))
    .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                     Collectors.mapping (Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                                         Collectors.toList())));
```

The result is:

```
{L1=[com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@6cd8737, com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@22f71333, com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@13969fbe, com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@6aaa5eb0], L10=[com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@6cd8737], L7=[com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@22f71333], L8=[com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@6aaa5eb0], L9=[com.codebroker.dea.test.TestObject@13969fbe]}
```

In order to see which `TestObject` instances were returned, lets override `TestObject`'s `toString()` as follows, so that it returns a `String` matching the corresponding `t#` variable names:

```
public String toString ()
{
  return "t" + differentValue;
}
```

Now the output `Map` is printed as:

```
{L1=[t6, t1, t4, t2], L10=[t6], L7=[t1], L8=[t2], L9=[t4]}
```

This is not the exact output you expected (the grouping is the same, but the `TestObject` instances are not), but it is the output that matches the `s` `Map` that you generated.